# Looping in list and creating a new one but there was a problem in append function

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-c7abd00c7a36> in <cell line: 7>()
      7 for word in feedback_list :
      8   if word not in rejected_words :
----> 9     new_feedback =  new_feedback.append(str(word))
     10     print(new_feedback)
     11   else :

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'?
```

Comment: `.append()` updates the actual list, it does not return anything.

Comment: `append` on lists returns `None`. You're not supposed to assign its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Explaination : append on lists returns None

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = a.append(3)
>>> print(b)
None
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```